# Not getting correct data when exporting JSON to Excel. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, excel, xlsx

The goal is to be able to export JSON data into an xlsx-file. I have seccsesfully been able to create the file by pressing a button, but for some reason I do not get the correct data inside of the excel-file.

**The data with console.log():**

[image: Console.log() data]

**What I get in the Excel-file:**

[image: Wrong excel]

It seems like the excel-file has just written the amount of objects.

**Small snippet of what i need it to look like:**

[image: Excel, what i need it to look like]

**JavaScript:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#export").click(function() {
        const jsonData = excelExportData;
        var jsonDataObject = eval(jsonData);        
        exportWorksheet(jsonDataObject);
    }); 
});


function exportWorksheet(jsonObject) {
    var myFile = "myFile.xlsx";
    var myWorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(jsonObject);
    var myWorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(myWorkBook, myWorkSheet, "myWorkSheet");
    XLSX.writeFile(myWorkBook, myFile);
  }
```

This is the code i have. excelExportData is the data that i am trying to convert.

Thanks in advance, and please ask if you want any extra information.

**NOTE:**
**The excelExportData is a variable that took data from an JSON-file and was filtered using for-loops and such. This process is happening in another js-file, not the same file as the code i shared.**

Comment: Please don't use eval. Use `JSON.parse` instead. Then after parsing log the data and see what you get.

Comment: @code I changed the eval into JSON.parse(jsonData), but i ended up getting an error code that i dont understand: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'o', "[object Obj"... is not valid JSON

Comment: They're your go. Your bug originates from the file that generated the prepared data. I believe the problem is really simple to solve if you post the code to that file.